# np.where to check on True for 1st column then on another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

i have below dataframe with `np.where` condition as:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data = {'First':[1,2,4,6,2,7,8,9],'Second':[4,6,7,3,1,3,9,3]})
df['First_check']=np.where(df['First']==2,'T','F')

df

   First    Second  First_check
0       1       4       F
1       2       6       T
2       4       7       F
3       6       3       F
4       2       1       T
5       7       3       F
6       8       9       F
7       9       3       F
```

Now i want to check for `df['Second']==3` but only after `df['First_check']=='T'` also i want only
**first occurance** of condition.

Below is My desired output:

```
   First    Second  First_check Second_check
0       1       4       F           F
1       2       6       T           F
2       4       7       F           F
3       6       3       F           T
4       2       1       T           F
5       7       3       F           T
6       8       9       F           F
7       9       3       F           F
```

Edit: i want `df['Second']==3` to become True But 1st  `df['First_check']=='T'` should become True then it may or may not be on same row.
say for `row 2` `df['First_check']=T` then it should check next rows 2,3,4... for `df['Second']==3` it matched at `row 4th`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

Criteria:

- Step 1: Look for value in `'First_check'`. If the value is 'T', reset the
  flag to check for `3` in `Second`
- Step 2: Now check for `3` in `Second`. Turn the value of the first `3` to
  `'T'`. All subsequent `3` should be `'F'` until you get a new `T` in
  `'First_check'`
- Step 3: When you get a new `'T'`, return to Step 1 and continue.

To do this, you need to look back both `'First_check'` and `'Second'`

Here's code to solve for it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(data = {'First':[1,2,4,6,2,7,8,9],'Second':[4,6,7,3,1,3,9,3]})

df['First_check']=np.where(df['First']==2,'T','F')
print (df)

df['tempF'] = df.groupby((df['First_check'].eq('T')).cumsum()).cumcount()+1
df['tempS'] = df.groupby((df['Second'].eq(3)).cumsum()).cumcount()+1
df['Second_check'] = np.where((df['tempS'] == 1) & (df['tempF'] == df['tempS'].shift(1)),'T','F')
df.drop(['tempF','tempS'],axis=1,inplace=True)
print (df)
```

The output is as per your required output:

```
   First  Second First_check Second_check
0      1       4           F            F
1      2       6           T            F
2      4       7           F            F
3      6       3           F            T
4      2       1           T            F
5      7       3           F            T
6      8       9           F            F
7      9       3           F            F
```

Comment: is this the Fastest approach for it?

Comment: For a complicated lookback like this, we cannot do a simple apply, You need to do groupby. I think this is the best way I know of. Let's timeit and find out

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can create a new Series where `2`s and `3`s are filled in while other places have `nan`s, and then you can do a forward fill on this new Series, which will give a Series with `2`s and `3`s only (with possibly `nan`s at the beginning). Finally you can check if `3`s in the `Second` has a preceding value of `2` in the `preceding` column:

```
# firstly merge two and three into a single Series and do a forward fill
preceding = df.First.shift(-1).where(
    df.First.shift(-1).eq(2), 
    df.Second.where(df.Second.eq(3))
).ffill()

preceding
#0    2.0
#1    2.0
#2    2.0
#3    2.0
#4    2.0
#5    3.0
#6    3.0
#7    3.0
#Name: First, dtype: float64

# after the forward fill if a 3 is preceded by a 2, then it should be True
df.Second.eq(3) & preceding.shift().eq(2)
#0    False
#1    False
#2    False
#3     True
#4    False
#5     True
#6    False
#7    False
#Name: First, dtype: bool
```

Comment: it is working but fails when on equal row due to shift may be. say if `row 2`  have 2 and 3 on `df.First` and `df.Second` resp.

Comment: Hmm, do you want the result to be `True` or `False` if a single row has both 2 and 3 ?

Comment: i want `True`  for it

Comment: You should be able to handle the case by shifting `First` backward first. And when checking `3`s use `Second` column not the combined.